# Join two data frames based on date and serial number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'serialNo':['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','ffff','aaaa','bbbb','aaaa'],
               'Name':['Sayonti','Ruchi','Tony','Gowtam','Toffee','Tom','Sayonti'],
               'testName':   [4402, 3747 ,5555,8754,1234,9876,3602],
               'moduleName':   ['singing', 'dance','booze', 'vocals','drama','paint','singing'],
               'endResult': ['WARNING', 'FAILED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED','WARNING','FAILED','WARNING'],
               'Date':['2018-10-5','2018-10-6','2018-10-7','2018-10-8','2018-10-9','2018-10-10','2018-10-8']})`

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'serialNo':['aaaa','bbbb','aaaa','ffff','xyzy','aaaa'],
               'Food':['Strawberry','Coke','Pepsi','Nuts','Apple','Candy'],
               'Work':   ['AP', 'TC','OD', 'PU','NO','PM'],
               'Date':['2018-10-1','2018-10-6','2018-10-2','2018-10-3','2018-10-5','2018-10-10']
               })
```

I want to join the two which I can achieve this way:

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['serialNo','Date'],how='inner')
```

But I want to make some changes to this in the way that the two data frames join doing a certain check on the date columns that is I want to check that df2['Date'] is within 3 days of df1['Date']. I do not want to add a separate column to check this condition and want to do it on the fly such that this condition is checked while joining. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think you can, at least without creating a separate column, or doing a larger merge on just `'serialNo'` and then subsetting afterwards. `pd.merge_asof` gets you close, but it only guarantees a 1:1 merge so you wouldn't get all possibilities.

Comment: @ALollz so creating a new column to check the date is the only option such that I don't loose all possibilities?

Comment: I think Chris A's solution is the simplest way to achieve this. If you truly want it to be done 'on the fly' wrap it in a function where you pass the two DataFrames and the number of days, and have this just return the subset.

Answer (score 2):

You could join only on `serialNo` then filter the result post-join:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='serialNo' ,how='inner')
result = result[result.Date_x.sub(result.Date_y).abs().dt.days.le(3)]
```

#### Update

Based on your comment below, remove the `.abs()` chained method and use `.between()` instead of `.le()`:

```
result = result[result.Date_x.sub(result.Date_y).dt.days.between(0,3)]
```

Comment: yeah I did it this way @Chris A as I couldn't achieve it at once. Thanks !

Comment: I just realized that is checking whether the Date_y is within 3 days of Date_x but I actually I wanted it to check if the Date_y is within 3 days after Date_x. so it should be Date_x + range(3days) how would that be achieved??

Comment: @sayo see updated answer, does this solve your problem?

Comment: this is perfect :) Thanks so much!